# How to update matplotlib at nonuniform interval

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I am getting data from a sensor at not fixed interval. When it completes 90 frames I want to plot it. I am adding rectangular patches. I am not able to update the figure. 
I guess I can not use Funcanimation as I do not have fixed interval.

I want to make a function when I call it, it updates the figure.

I have make a temporary function which should update after a while loop but it does not .

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
import numpy as np
import pylab
from random import randint

def arsplot(rho,phi,wid,height):

    for i in range(len(rho)):

        phi[i]=phi[i]+randint(0,9)
        rho[i]=rho[i]+randint(-5,5)
        ax1.add_patch(patches.Rectangle((rho[i],phi[i]),wid[i],height[i]))    


rho=[12, 16, 18, 4, 11, 6, 17]
phi=[12,16,18,4,11,6,17]
wid=[2,2,2,2,2,2,2]
height=[1,1,1,1,1,1,1]

fig1=plt.figure(figsize=(15,32))
ax1=fig1.add_subplot(111, aspect='equal')
plt.grid(True)
pylab.xlim([-25,45])
pylab.ylim([-15,55])

while True:

    arsplot(rho,phi,wid,height) #function call

    plt.show()
```

Comment: See examples in https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/4947 (yes, that should be in the docs, but it isn't)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer of my own question.
use 'set_data(x,y)' command. Here is sample abstract code:

```
plot_x = [0]
plot_y = [0]

fig1=plt.figure(figsize=(15,32))
ax1=fig1.add_subplot(111, aspect='equal')
Ln, = ax1.plot(plot_x,plot_y,'ro')
.....     #your function for changing x,y points.
.....
.....
Ln.set_data(plot_x,plot_y)
plt.pause(0.01)
```